Which is the Movie Containing Violence Against A Family in Black and White
I remember a movie that I watched on TV almost 10 years ago. The movie was Black and White. 
I remember some details. Not too much. A young man wearing a white short and holding a Golf sticks asks for eggs. Or there was something about eggs. He asks the Wife for the eggs. Then they started to attack the family but I don't remember how. And he had a friend or two who were going to involve the violence against this family. 
Family, as far as I remember, consisted at least three. Father, Wife, Daughter and may be their son. A little boy. 
I may have a doubt about the color of the movie. But I think it was black-white. 
Somehow I recall a title like "Sonny" or may be one of the character's name was Sonny. But that may be completely different thing. I just have a slight thought about "Sonny" name. Thanks for your time. 

Funny Games (1997) or
Funny Games (2007)

Two psychotic young men take a mother, father, and son hostage in
  their vacation cabin and force them to play sadistic "games" with one
  another for their own amusement.


+1 I couldn't imagine anything else having the same premise, must've been a false memory about B/W. Probably the original, if it's really about 10 years ago on TV.      Oh, +quinone I'd recommend you don't watch the remake unless you're really good at detaching yourself emotionally and view it as something completely different - lest you have the original completely destroyed by inexplicable watering-down pandering

Yeah 1997 version is exactly what I was looking for thanks.
